# Advanced Start up options and bcdedit missing in windows 10 with deepin(Linux) dual boot

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, drivers, multi-boot

I have installed Windows 10 64bit 1809 os build 17763 along with Deepin 64bit 15.10. Both the system working well. I have a problem with the Windows Advanced startup option it is not there when I restart to advanced startup there is only one option and that is to Turn off the PC.

I want to install a digitally unsigned driver that is Dolby Advanced Audio V2 that is why I want to disable the digital signature enforcement. I have tried the solution from this link [How to disable driver signature enforcement on Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/driver-signature-enforcement-windows-10/) I tried all solutions from the link, solution 1, 3, and 4 did not work for me and 2nd I changed as per instruction but when I tried to install it did not work.

I tried bcdedit but I got error **The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The system cannot find the file specified.**. I need help with this.